# jQuery AJAX - POST data to IMG tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, image

**file.php**

```
<?php
  $variable = 'mainImage';
?>

<div>
  <img src="image.php">
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="">
```

---

**I am trying to do the following:**

When the button is clicked **$variable** should be passed to **image.php** and the image should reload accordingly.
Yes, i know we can update the **src** to **image.php?variable=mainImage**. ( $_GET  )

But is it possible to send **$variable** through $_POST without refreshing the page, but refreshing only the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably accomplish this using [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to get something like:

```
// Instead of simply storing the URL as the src attribute,
//   execute the post and shove the data into a data URL
$.post('image.php', {variable: 'value'}, function(data) {
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
});
```

There might also be some useful information in the [minimal image transport](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) section of the `ajaxTransport` documentation about how to more tightly integrate such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use jQuery to accomplish this. I suggest giving your image an id before doing this, this way we can select that particular image and grab the source, so do this.

```
<img id="main-image"  src="image.php">

$(function(){
   var main_image = $('#main-image'); 
   var url = main_image.attr('src'); 
   $.post( url, { variable: '<?php echo $mainImage ?>' }, function( data ){
      main_image.attr('src', data);  
   })
});
```

Comment: Please note that the response of image.php is a header with binary data, so data in your example is binary and cannot be assigned to src. Or maybe i misunderstood something? Thank you for your comment.